Frequency sampling

How does nyquist sampling theorem works. For example, given a signal with rang 0.5 to 1.5 Hz, why does the fs is 2 Hz?

Hi! Welcome here! this is a bit broad, especially because it's literally covered in every text book on signal processing, including the one accompanying these figures!
